# Using Euler's method to compute the frequency of a nonlinear pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, eulers-method

In my studies of numerical methods I have come across the following exercise:

> We consider the following second-order ODE $$\ddot{\theta}+\sin(\theta) = 0 $$ and we reduce it to a two-dimensional system of first-order ODEs using the 2-vector $$y(t) = \begin{pmatrix} y_1(t) \\ y_2(t) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \theta(t) \\ \dot{\theta}(t) \end{pmatrix} $$ to get the first-order 2-dimensional system of ODEs $$ 
> y'(t) = \begin{pmatrix} y_2(t) \\ -\sin(y_1(t)) \end{pmatrix} = f(y(t)) $$ We are asked to use Euler's method given by the recurrence relation $$ y_n = y_{n-1} + hf(y_{n-1}) $$
> A.We are asked to choose initial conditions for $ y(0) $and use Euler's method to compute one full swing of the pendulum.

> B. We are asked to use part A with a step size $h$ small enough to compute the frequency of the pendulum to get 3 digits of accuracy and explain.

> C. We are asked to compute the theoretical error bound (as hints, we are asked to look at the Lipschitz constant of $f(y)$, to use energy conservation to obtain a bound on $\lVert y''(t) \rVert $ and to turn the error estimate for $y$ into the error estimate for the period of one swing).

I did part A with a computer, but I do not know how to do parts B and C. For one thing, part B has me stumped. When my stepsize $h$ is very small on the order of $10^{-3}$ I see a periodic solution which I can extract a time period from $T$ and the frequency would be $ f=\frac{1}{T} $. But here is my question: how can I find and justify a stepsize $h$ small enough so that $f$ is computed with 3 digits of accuracy? This is what has me stumped. I think I also need help on part C. I thank all helpers.

Comment: This might be a naive suggestion, but what about repeating the process for smaller and smaller step-sizes, rounding off the frequency to 3 decimal places, and stopping at the $h$ after which the rounded frequency doesn't change?

Comment: @Philip thank you but actually what I comoute is the period $T$ and I take its inverse so maybe one can take the function $\frac{1}{x}$ and see how accurate $x$ must be so that its inverse is computed with 3 digits of accuracy. What do you think?

Comment: Not sure why you won't be able to do this even when you take the inverse, maybe I'm missing something? Given that you can calculate the frequency (albeit with some imprecision) given a value of $h$, if you repeated the process iteratively you should arrive at an $h$ below which the frequency is precise up to 3 decimals.

Comment: @Philip yes I guess that would work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B. In first order, you get the root $T_h$ of a function $f_h(t)=a(t)+hb(t)$ as approximation of a root $T_*$ of $a$. Expanding $f_h(T_*+hv)=a(T_*)+\dot a(T_*)hv+hb(T_*)+O(h^2)$ for $T_h=T_*+hv$ gives an estimate of $v=-\frac{ b(T_*)}{\dot a(T_*)}$.

[image]

<sub>*the numerical approximation $f_h(t)=θ_h(t)$ of step size $h$ seen as $a(t)+hb(t)+...$ with $a(t)=θ_0(t)$ the exact solution, for several values of $h$. It is visible that not only the vertical value has a perturbation proportional to $h$, but also the root location.*</sub>

So if you know an approximation for $\dot a(T_h)$ and $b(T_h)$, you get $T_h+h\frac{b(T_h)}{\dot a(T_h)}$ as improved root estimation of the root $T_*$ of $a=θ_0$. The important part is that $h\frac{b(T_h)}{\dot a(T_h)}$ is an error estimate of $T_h$.
$\dot a(T_h)=\dot θ_0(T_h)$ you get directly from the differential equation, $b(T_h)$ can be estimated by comparing the results for two different step sizes.

Which raises the question of if it is simpler to just estimating the error of $T_h$ by comparing it to $T_{2h}$. So compute the error for some relatively large but still reasonable $h$ and then scale $h$ so that the expected scaled-down error is in the desired region.

[image]

<sub>*Numerical values for $T_h$ with a secant line. The slope for small $h$ is a little smaller than $0.5$, but still this rough estimate is sufficient to determine $h=10^{-3}$ as sufficient to get 3 correct digits after the dot.
\begin{array}{c|c}
h&T_h\\\hline
0.000500  & 6.70013638\\
0.001000 &  6.70029805\\
0.002000  & 6.70062424
\end{array}*</sub>

C. just asks for bounds on $|b(T)|$ based on the global error formula $$e(T)\le\frac{M_2}{2L}(e^{LT}-1)h$$ where $M_2$ is a bound for the second derivative around the solution and $L$ the Lipschitz constant. $\dot a(T)$ can again be used directly, if you are looking for a root of $a(t)=\dot θ(t)$, then the value of $\dot a(t)=\ddot θ(t)=-\sinθ(t)$ is known approximately because $θ(T)$ will still be close to the maximum amplitude.

Comment: thank you for a great answer but I just want to make sure what is the root $T_h$ you speak of in terms of my equation? Is $T_h$ the time period?

Comment: Yes, $T_h$ is the period estimate that you compute using step size $h$. I hope you use the root of the linear interpolation of the last step.

Comment: thank you very much. I just need to understand what $a(t),b(t)$ are in relation to my equation. And how do you arrive at the approximation of the root of $a(t)$ the way you did? Thank you again

Comment: If you expand the numerical solution $y_h(t)$ with step size $h$ in $h$, then to first order you get $y_h(t)=y(t)+hc_1(t)+O(h^2)$. As said in the end, your choice seems to be to take $a(t)=y_2(t)=\dotθ(t)$, looking for the second root. A faster choice would be to take $a(t)=y_1(t)=θ(t)$ and look for its first root to find a quarter of the period. $b(t)$ is the corresponding error coefficient. One could establish a differential equation for it, but the quick method is Richardson extrapolation.

Comment: thank you  very much